# Not Able to Create New Feature Class From Selecting By Attribute

Tags: arcpy

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to create new feature class from a shapefile based on selecting by attribute and saving the new feature class in a Geodatabase?

The file is adding to the GDB but it is empty on attributes and geometry.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy    

# Local variables:
Dataset = "D:\\GIS\\TPK\\src\\New Folder\\lui.gdb\\Dataset"
Louisiana = "Louisiana"
Louisiana__3_ = Louisiana
mm = "D:\\GIS\\TPK\\src\\New Folder\\lui.gdb\\Dataset\\mm"

# Process: Select Layer By Attribute
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Louisiana, "NEW_SELECTION", "\"NAME_2\" = 'Acadia'")

# Process: Create Feature Class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(Dataset, "mm", "POLYGON", "Louisiana", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", "", "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: Use copyfeaures instead of create.

Comment: Use Select instead of SelectLayerByAttribute and  CreateFeatureClass.

Answer (score 1):

CreateFeatureClass creates an empty feature class as you have observed.

I recommend using the  Select_analysis tool  instead of SelectLayerByAttribute and CreateFeatureClass.